# Is Youtube using HTTP Live Streaming?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, http, youtube

I am looking into HTTP Live-streaming. Apple says it will only support large videos with the HTTP live-streaming protocol

I want to show a Youtube video in iOS, Is Youtube using HTTP live-streaming so that this is possible?

Comment: Did you try using the Youtube API?

Comment: No @Anil, I have not tried it.

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyKanagaraj I'm trying the same. Have you solved your problem.

Comment: @VarunMehta Kind of solved. Posted my answer. Kindly up vote my question and answer if you find it useful.

Comment: @Anil Hi Anil, I have tried YouTube API. Its working fine. Could able to get lot of information from YouTube by using that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually we never know what kind of streaming YouTube is using. But Apple will not reject if you are showing an YouTube video in your Application.

We can show YouTube videos using iFrame in UIWebView. It seems lot of application doing the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp

Comment: If you want to know what kind of streaming YouTube uses you can just sniff network traffic.